# Does HUAWEI Analytics Kit support automatic resending for data that failed to be reported?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

Data reporting may fail due to network errors or other causes. Does HUAWEI Analytics Kit support automatic resending of the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an event fails to be reported, the event is automatically saved to the cache. The cached event can be resent in either of the following ways:

Waits for 30s and resends the event together with the next event.

Resends the event when the app exits. To-be-resent data in the cache is cleared only when the cache clearing API is called or the user device is restored to factory settings.